# XML Deserializer - object is empty

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I want to converts objects to xml and reverse. I can serialize my objects without any problems to an xml document using this method:

```
public static void SaveObjectToXML(T _obj, string fileName)
{
   XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
   FileStream str = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
   ser.Serialize(str, _obj);
   str.Close();
}
```

But with the Deserializer I've got some problems... While the process I get no Errors or problems (same for calling methods of it) but when I try do acess any members the problem begins. All members are null (same for methods acessing any members). Heres the code:

```
public static T SaveXMLToObject(string fileName)
{
   XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
   T dataSet = (T)ser.Deserialize(sr);
   return dataSet;
}
```

Any Ideas?

---

edit:

OK I just added the using Statement, thanks for that :)
The complete classes are a bit to much, but they look like this:

```
public class User
{
   private string _name;
   public string Name
   {
     get { return _name; }
     set { }
   }
}

public class AllUser
{
   private User[] _users;
   public User[] Users
   {
      get { return _users; }
      set { }
   }
}
```

Comment: Besides not using `using`, I dont really see any problems with this code.  Can you post the `T` definition here?

Comment: OK I just added the using Statement, thanks for that :)

The complete classes are a bit to much, but they look like this:

    public class User
    {
     private string _name;
     public string Name
     {
       get { return _name; }
       set { }
     }
    }
    
    public class AllUser
    {
      private User[] _users;
      public User[] Users
      {
        get { return _users; }
        set { }
      }
    }

Comment: sry, but I can only comment :/ and found out that u can edit my post :)

Comment: Once I fill in your setters, this works fine for me here.  I can post my full example, but I'm guessing the issue is something else.

Comment: damn, I need some sleep :). I assigned the value to private members I used for internal calculation and they have almost the same name :/ need to change that. Fixed the setter and everything works like it should. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming sample code is complete I am not surprised at all. You have empty setters (which is what serialization will use). Don't just satisfy serialization error by adding empty setter. It is required for populating your data.

Changes that to

```
set { _users = value; }
```

and it should work

Comment: I think he just left it off trimming down his example

Comment: damn, I need some sleep :). I assigned the value to private members I used for internal calculation and they have almost the same name :/ need to change that. Fixed the setter and everything works like it should. thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need to mark the classes you are deserializing to as `[Serializable]`. For example:

```
[Serializable]
public class User
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure XmlSerializer does not care about SerializableAttribute

Comment: @Kipaboy: Maybe those errors could help us out. @liho1eye: You're right, the `SerializableAttribute` is not required (even though most examples of XML serialization and deserialization show it being used), but it's good practice to use it, if only for the purpose of indicating there's some type of serialization happening with those classes. I was wrong to suggest that it would fix anything.

Comment: @Cory I posted my fault 1 post above. I assigned the value to wrong private members... I couldn't reproduce the errors I had with the SerializableAttribute, but I had these errors about 1 week ago and worked on other scripts!